Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message returned: Command died with <Signals.SIGKILL: 9>
What am I trying to do

I am using CDK to build a stack that can run a python app
EC2 to run the python application
RDS instance to run the PosgreSQL database that connects with EC2
Custom VPC to contain everything
I have a local pg_dump of my PostgreSQL database that I want to upload to an S3 bucket which contains all my database data
I used CDK to create an S3 bucket and tried to upload my pg_dump file

What is happening

For a small file size < 1MB it seems to work just fine

For my dev dump (About 160 MB in size), it gives me an error
Received response status [FAILED] from
custom resource. Message returned:
Command '['/opt/awscli/aws', 's3',
'cp', 's3://cdk-<some-hash>.zip',
'/tmp/tmpjtgcib_f/<some-hash>']' died
with <Signals.SIGKILL: 9>. (RequestId:
<some-request-id>)

❌  SomeStack failed: Error: The stack
named SomeStack failed creation, it may
need to be manually deleted from the
AWS console: ROLLBACK_COMPLETE:
Received response status [FAILED] from
custom resource. Message returned:
Command '['/opt/awscli/aws', 's3',
'cp', 's3://cdk-<some-hash>.zip',
'/tmp/tmpjtgcib_f/<some-hash>']' died
with <Signals.SIGKILL: 9>. (RequestId:
<some-request-id>)
at
FullCloudFormationDeployment.monitorDeployment

(/Users/vr/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:455:10568)
at process.processTicksAndRejections
(node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Object.deployStack2 [as
deployStack]

(/Users/vr/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:458:199716)
at async

/Users/vr/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:458:181438

Code
export class SomeStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // The code that defines your stack goes here

    const dataImportBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, "DataImportBucket", {
      blockPublicAccess: s3.BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL,
      bucketName: "ch-data-import-bucket",
      encryption: s3.BucketEncryption.KMS_MANAGED,
      enforceSSL: true,
      minimumTLSVersion: 1.2,
      publicReadAccess: false,
      removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
      versioned: false,
    });
    
    // This folder will contain my dump file in .tar.gz format
    const dataImportPath = join(__dirname, "..", "assets");

    const deployment = new s3d.BucketDeployment(this, "DatabaseDump", {
      destinationBucket: dataImportBucket,
      extract: true,
      ephemeralStorageSize: cdk.Size.mebibytes(512),
      logRetention: 7,
      memoryLimit: 128,
      retainOnDelete: false,
      sources: [s3d.Source.asset(dataImportPath)],
    });
  }
}

My dev dump file is only about 160 MB but production one is close to a GB. Could someone kindly tell me how I can upload bigger files without this error?

Your lambda is running out of memory. Since it's extracing the .zip archive, it needs to be able to fit its contents in memory. The actual storage size also need to be sufficient - the default is 512 MiB.
Set the memory to e.g. 2 GB and the storage size to the same:
    memoryLimit: 2048,
    ephemeralStorageSize: Size.gibityes(2),


you sir are a real lifesaver, that actually worked! My production file would be about 700 mb so should I put the memoryLimit as 4 times or something? What about ephemeral storage? default is 512 mb right?

Yeah, good point about the storage size, added to the answer

snce we are on the topic, i wanted to ask. as of now it seems lambda has an upper limit of 10GB, what if you wanted to upload a 1TB file to s3 via cdk,is there no way to stream to s3 via cdk?

No way using the BucketDeployment construct, no.
